# Restricting role escalation in AWS iam permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

Is it possible to create an AWS role (with `"iam:CreateRole"` permissions) to prevent it having privilege escalation, and only allow it to create new roles with a specific set of permissions e.g: `"s3:GetObject"`?

I am not sure if `PermissionsBoundary` is what I am after something like (in terraform):

```
  statement {
    sid       = "AddRole"
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["iam:CreateRole", "s3:CreateBucket"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:iam::${var.cluster.aws_account_id}:role/*"]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      values   = [aws_iam_policy.boundary_role_iam_policy.arn]
      variable = "iam:PermissionsBoundary"
    }
  }
```

where `boundary_role_iam_policy` is a role with just allow `"s3:GetObject"`?

Comment: Great, I'm glad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a permission boundary is exactly what you need.

Add the following as a permission boundary of the role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "iam:CreateUser"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: And how it would help in this case? As I understand it, users should have ability to create roles, with only specific access - e.g. get object. May I wrongly understand this question?

Comment: *users should have ability to create roles, with only specific access - e.g. get object.* That's exactly what my policy does

Comment: No, your policy allows only access to create roles, and get objects. If the user will have access to create role, and attach any policy, then it wouldn't stop privilege escalation

Comment: @ZabielskiGabriel I suggest you read the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html

Comment: lol, sorry... I misunderstood @maxisme question... NVM :l

Answer (score 0):

@Eidt

Sorry, I misunderstood your question - yes, your `permissions boundary` attached to the user should have the maximum access, that you want to grant to the users, and condition that you pasted in the question.

---

Also, I will leave this piece because it is a way in which you can do the same.

It is possible to do it using [SCP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html), and `Permissions boundary`.

- ### `SCP`

  - should prevent access to create roles without attached `Permissions boundary`
  - preventing the ability to read/edit/detach `Permissions boundary` (for everything beyond you)
- ### `Permissions boundary Policy`

  - as above - max permissions and conditional

Comment: You don't need to use scp's to enforce permission boundaries

Comment: @Paolo yes, it is possible to achieve the same result with permissions boundary only - In my opinion, it's just easier way